# Facebook action button link for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I am creating a Facebook for an app which is supported on both iOS and Android. While introducing the action button the Facebook post, the option is to provide only one link. How can I allow the click on the button to direct to Apple iTunes or Google Playstore depending on the mobile on which the button was clicked? I did try to do some search in regards to this and there are some discussions on deep linking which i don't fully understand. Is there a simple way achieve without having to modify anything on app?

Answer (score 0):

Found the below website for creating short link which can direct to Apple iTunes or Android Playstore

tosto.re